# How to convert a single line json into multiline by sed command

Tags: json, pyspark

Consider following JSON snippet:

```
  [{
        "first": "rand_data",
        "second": "rand2_data"
    }, {
        "first  " : "for{change } in code",
        "second" : "change[it]"

    }]
```

I have a big json file around 20 gb on hdfs which is a single line. On reading through pyspark . it failed giving error (SPARK read.json throwing java.io.IOException: Too many bytes before newline) . I want to add new line inside json file using sed or any command so that spark can able to load it.

Comment: Can you please elaborate your use case? What language are you using? Why do you think splitting each data-point (each field) into multi-line would yield better processing? Are you trying to split *key* `temp` and its *value* `fun karo`?

Comment: `regex` cannot be used for such a task. There is no *"better processing"* for JSON. The only processing that can be done on a JSON is to decode it into the data structures used to create it; and, as long as the JSON is correct, decoding works the same no matter the formatting of the JSON. Keep your JSONs safe, don't break them by attempting to "improve" their formatting. It's not worth it.

Comment: I have a big json file  around 20 gb on hdfs which is a single line. On reading through pyspark . it failed giving error (SPARK read.json throwing java.io.IOException: Too many bytes before newline) . I want to add new line inside json file using sed or any command so that spark can able to load it.